# Create a new pandas column, as the result of a subset of the rows of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a problem where I have a dataframe that consists of dates, prices, and daily returns (todays price / yday price - 1).

```
                   NAV    Return
Date                            
01/01/2015  100.000000       NaN
01/02/2015   97.002676 -0.029973
01/03/2015   96.123553 -0.009063
01/04/2015   95.877838 -0.002556
01/05/2015   96.257080  0.003955
```

My goal is to create another column in the data, that is the standard deviation of a subset of the data (5 days worth). So the first 5 values would be null, but then the rest of the column would contain the standard deviation of that row and the preceding 5 rows. So it would look like this:

```
                   NAV    Return       std
Date                                      
01/01/2015  100.000000       NaN       NaN
01/02/2015   97.002676 -0.029973       NaN
01/03/2015   96.123553 -0.009063       NaN
01/04/2015   95.877838 -0.002556       NaN
01/05/2015   96.257080  0.003955       NaN
...                ...       ...       ...
12/26/2015  101.167791 -0.000612  0.008190
12/27/2015  102.924456  0.017364  0.007941
12/28/2015  100.216064 -0.026314  0.010082
12/29/2015   98.383266 -0.018288  0.014706
12/30/2015   96.853369 -0.015550  0.015137
```

I figured out one way to do this, by creating a list based on an if/then statement, but it takes a long time to run. I'm wondering if there is a quicker way to accomplish this task, ideally using vectorization. Here is the code I came up with:

```
data = [] 
for row in range(len(df)): 
    if row < 5: 
        data.append(None) 
    else: 
        data.append(np.std(df['Return'][row-5:row]))
df['std'] = data
```

Comment: can you copy and paste the cells in StackOverflow for #1 and #2? You can use the code snippet feature or press the space bar four times on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rolling:

```
df['std'] = df['Return'].rolling(6).std()
```

Comment: This is perfect, it did the trick. And runs so quickly! Thanks for the help Bruno